# Serialize HashMap to a JSON string while avoiding certain fields in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a map as below:

```
Map map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");
map.put("key3", "value3");
```

I need to convert this map into a JSON string. I know that this can be done using Jackson as below:

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map);
```

The problem is, I do not want to map `key3` to the String. The output String should be as below:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

Is there any way to avoid certain fields from the HashMap while serializing it to a String? Moreover, I want to add certain fields to the String while serializing. For instance, I need to add a field called "key4" with a value "value4". Thus, the final String should be:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key4":"value4"}
```

How do I do this using Jackson? Or is there any other way to do this in Java?

Comment: Why not modify the Map before serializing it? Remove key3 and add key4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to serialize a `HashMap` like this, you should implement a custom serializer. Here is one example:

```
public class CustomSerializer extends StdSerializer<Map> {
    protected CustomSerializer() {
        super(Map.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Map map, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
            if(!"key3".equals(key)){
                jsonGenerator.writeStringField((String) key, (String) map.get(key));
            }
        }
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("key4","value4");
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("key1","value1");
        map.put("key2","value2");
        map.put("key3","value3");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule serializerModule = new SimpleModule("SerializerModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, "mt", "customSerializerTest"));
        serializerModule.addSerializer(new CustomSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(serializerModule);

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(map));
    }
}

Output:
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key4":"value4"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are serializing a POJO, you can use the `@JsonIgnore` annotation, but in this case, this is not an option, so you should make a copy of the `HashMap`, and do whatever operations on it, what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way really is to modify the Map.

However, if you want, you can actually use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` on `Map` type as well. So, something like:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "key3" })
public class MyFilteringMap extends HashMap<String,String> { }
```

It is not possible to add properties via annotations.

But it is possible to use `@JsonAnySetter` and `@JsonAnyGetter` annotations to make a POJO look like a `Map`. This would allow combining of approaches for filtering, as well as some "standard" properties and other misc properties. See this -- http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html -- for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Jackson Custom Serializers - http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers. I think it's convenient option for your use case. Using own serializer you can make transparent object processing in `serialize` method - for example you can copy map to another avoiding certain fields etc.