# Map to JSON - ignore specific keys

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I want to serialize a java map into json and I can definitely use either jackson or gson.

But when I serialize, I want to ignore specify key. Is it possible?

Map is . I don't have/want my Map backed by a POJO because the keys are very generic and could  be anything. I understand if it was a POJO, we can use Ignore annotation to achieve.

Comment: I saw a post maybe could be of your interest, they created a custom map serializer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475174/serialize-hashmap-to-a-json-string-while-avoiding-certain-fields-in-java

Comment: Maybe you can just create a copy (or use the original) and delete the values you're not interested in?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class that extends `HashMap`:

```
public class MyMap extends HashMap<String, Object> {
}
```

and then register a custom serializer, like:

```
public class MyMapSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyMap> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(MyMap arg0, Type arg1, JsonSerializationContext arg2) {
        JsonObject result = new JsonObject();

        for (String k : arg0.keySet()) {
            if (whatever your condition is) {
                result.add(k, arg0.get(k));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then when you create the Gson object you need to initialize it by passing an instance of the serializer:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(MyMap.class, new MyMapSerializer()).create();
```